# Django admin template display

Tags: django, django-admin

My django admin pages are displaying differently on local and on my hosting. The one on local is has better display.
Both are running Django 1.11.4.
What could have caused this?

[Image of Django admin with better display on local environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REeyE.png)

[Image of Django admin with slightly different display on hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P280D.png)

Comment: On the host you have the old style. To know why you have to see the details of where the host is getting its static files (server configuration, static configuration in Django, `collectstatic`).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it was pointing to the wrong django path on my hosting. After pointing it to the right django path, it displays fine now